# How do I know which process is accessing my hard drive when my Windows 10 was idle?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, process, idle

Many times I leave my Windows 10 idle on my PC, I notice that the HDD led is constantly on, indicating intensive access to the HDD.
But when I move the mouse or press any key, the led turns off, indicating that HDD access has stopped.
I think this could be some Windows scheduled task for disk optimization or something similar.
How can I see which process was making this access, even after it was stopped?

Comment: you can run sysinternals DiskMon or ProcMon to capture information, and then check it after you start interacting with the system again. Note however that no modern PC is ever actually idle.

Comment: Maybe something in Event Viewer could be consulted?

Comment: No, the eventvwr won't really help you, unless the offending process was writting to log information that is pertinent to your query. the built-in alerts and logging won't really tell you anything aobut what is running at a given time or what it is doinng.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *Task Manager* to show Disk I/O.

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> to open *Task Manager*.
- Turn to the *Details* tab.
- Right-click on the column headers and pick *Select columns*.
- Add *I/O reads* and *I/O writes*.
- Click on the *I/O reads* header to sort descending.

Now, leave the PC idle for a few minutes (not long enough for the screen to blank, though), and see what items pop to the top.

[image: Finding processes with high disk I/O]

If you use Microsoft Sysinternals' [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer), instead, you may add a column for I/O History, which displays a graph of I/O usage *over time*, so you can look at a snapshot of what process *was* using Disk I/O *before* you moved your mouse!

[image: I/O History in Process Explorer]

A WayBack Machine for processes! [Mr. Peabody](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vxZ6AAcvGWc) could have used this.

Comment: yeah if its a short idle bedore the offending process begins, I usually just keep process explorer open and let it go idle. for things that take longer to get started diskmon/procmon are a bit better (and provide much more detailed info), but I agree with your recommendations.